# Editing table data within PHP after adding a new column to MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, insert, col

I am creating a website using PHP and MYSQL which has 3 pages; Insert, Update & Delete. The insert page adds a new column to a database table. In my update page I want to be able to view all data which is in the table where the new column has been added. How would I go about this?  i.e if theres now 11 columns after the insert rather that 10 previous i want the update page to show

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | col10 | col11

data | data | data | data | data | data | data | data | data | data | data
```

Comment: 1) run select query 2) retrieve data 3) output html.

Comment: Why do you have altering procedures in php code?

Comment: You're adding columns - really? Or rows?

Comment: As it is a careers website where there's 10 careers with 10 results. Each question in the assessment has a rating of 1-5, in my insert query it adds a new column for a new question result

Comment: Why not table `results` with `id | question | result |` and every question will be new ROW, not column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with a table of mine:

```
<table>
    <tr>

<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "test");
/*
 * CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `col1` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `col2` int(11) NOT NULL
... // until col5
 */
$query = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'test' AND table_schema = 'test'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

// INSERT INTO `test`.`test` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`)
// VALUES ('10', '11', '12', '13', '14'), ('15', '16', '17', '18', '10');

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM test";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);


while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>
        <td><?=$row['column_name'];?></td>

<?php
}
?>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <?php
 while ($res = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

    $count_columns = $result->num_rows;

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count_columns; $i++) {
     ?>
        <td><?=$res['col'.$i.''];?></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
<?php

 }
```

---

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
 10     11      12       13     14
 15     16      17       18     10
```

That's without knowing the column names and their count. It's enough they have the same prefix "col".

After adding one new column:

```
    ALTER TABLE `test` ADD `col6` INT NOT NULL 
    UPDATE test SET col6 = col1+1
```

The same code (without any change) produces:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
 10     11      12       13     14      11
 15     16      17       18     10      16
```

P.S.: I'm still not encouraging this table structuring, where you need to add columns dynamicly

Answer (score 0):

Even adding columns (altering procedure) from PHP is bad practice for me, there might be different solution. You can retrieve the columns from information_schema:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'yourTable';

$row['column_name']; //will output the actual result of columns for that table
```

Also for actual result, you can name them "col1, col2", so you can iterate through the results and recieve variable like

```
$row['col'.$i.''];
```

Then you can recieve results for every column, also their names.

Comment: So i would have to do something like SELECT col1, col2 etc
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'yourTable';

$row['col1'],$row['col2']; etc?

Surely if i do this it will only display the columns which I already have without adding code to this manually?

Comment: No, SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name ='yourtable' will retrieve the column names of that table right now. You can also count them, pass to a variable, and make a simple `for` loop, to assign number to the string `col`.

Comment: Ah right, im with you now.. Will i then be able to edit the information within this then with further code?

Comment: I've posted a new answer with the whole example