# MySql SELECT get 1 record from multiple record

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-select-db

I have a table which looks something like :

> id name    qty price rev
>
> 1  book1    2  $10    0
>
> 2  book2    1  $5     0
>
> 3  book1    3  $15    1
>
> 4  book3    2  $10    0
>
> 5  book4    3  $15    0
>
> 6  book2    3  $15    1
>
> 7  book2    4  $20    2

and the data that will be displayed on the web is,

> no name    qty price  rev
>
> 1  book1    3   $15    1
>
> 2  book2    4   $20    2
>
> 3  book3    2   $10    0
>
> 4  book4    3   $15    0

This is the query that I use

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(qty*price) FROM data_ph_user ORDER BY id");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>
<!-- display result -->
<?php 
$resf1 = $res['SUM(qty*price)']; if($resf1 == 0){ echo '0'; }else{ echo $resf1; }
?>
<!-- end display -->
<?php } ?>
```

so, now how to get the data?

I've done various kinds of queries by using 'WHERE' but do not get results

Comment: What is `no`? This doesn't seem to have any meaning, is it just the row number? You should give more info how you convert the first table into the next, because if you sum up the books, you get 5...

Comment: @Cummosoft :Sorry, you're right. and I also do not provide information. thanks for the advice. If I can do my vote  i would give you +1 :D

Comment: no problem. But it's advisable next time you ask a question to be a bit more specific. It saves people that answer the question a lot of effort and filters out (good intended) wrong answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your point.. so you just want to select the line where qty is maximum per book name..  right??

try the below query

```
select
  name, qty, price, rev
from
  MyTestingTable
where
  qty = (select max(qty) from MyTestingTable i where i.Name = MyTestingTable.Name)
order by MyTestingTable.name
```

you can have a look on given [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9162c4/8) as well.. it will give you the desired result..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9162c4/8
[image]

Comment: your welcome.. initial I was little bit confused what exactly you want.. I will suggest you to always post some description as well.. that helps the people to understand your problem and provide you answer in correct way.. :)

Comment: sharman : actually i just want to find the total price of all of the book, but for a book that has the code rev 0 and if one of the books have been edited or revised so that taken last rev, and to the overall price of the book in the can is $ 60 after Book1 ($ 15) + book2 ($ 20) + book3 ($ 10) + book4 ($ 15),

total price = $ 60
query to display <?php 
$resf1 = $res['SUM(qty*price)']; if($resf1 == 0){ echo '0'; }else{ echo $resf1; }
?>
thanks, sorry my bad english

Comment: sorry but here in my query I am displaying for max qty not for max rev.. if you want for max rev. you have to change the query I proposed you.. just replace the field.. qty by rev.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `SUM` is an [*aggregate function*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). Such functions normally return one row: in this case, you would sum over the entire table **unless** you group by something.

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to list the highest revision of all elements?

```
SELECT *, MAX(rev) FROM data_ph_user GROUP BY `name`
```

Then it's only a matter of [typesetting it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334624/how-to-convert-mysql-table-to-html-table-to-match-columns-and-rows).